# Prevent jQuery from Scrolling on Fixed Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a site that has a fixed navigation bar at the top. The search input field uses jQuery to slide out in nav bar when the icon is clicked. When the user scrolls down on the page and clicks the icon, the page automatically scrolls back to the top. Is there a simple way to prevent this behavior in the event handler below?

```
$('.search-button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.search-field').animate({'width':'toggle'});
});
```

Comment: $('.search-button').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
    $('.search-field').animate({'width':'toggle'});
});

Comment: There isn;t enough code here for use to help you. Can you post the HTML for the icon/button as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.search-button').on('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); //If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.
$(this).hide(); 
$('.search-field').animate({'width':'toggle'}); });




pass the event e as argument and cancel the default behaviour
```

that will work

Comment: Answers are far more valuable with some explanation of how they work and *why*, rather than just the code. Teach a man to fish vs lighting him on fire, and that whole proverb. ;)